# Create Record from Array in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, record

I have an array, and I want to make a Record from this data. I have sth written but it doesn't work. Main problem is how to iterate my array with saving Record.

```
function createTypesWithTranslationsRecords(types: { header: string; translation: string }[]) : Record<string, string> {
  const locationTypesMap : Record<string, string> = types.forEach((type) => {type.header: type.translation});
  return locationTypesMap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```js
function createTypesWithTranslationsRecords(types: { header: string; translation: string }[]): Record<string, string> {
    const locationTypesMap: Record<string, string> = {};
    types.forEach((type) => {
        locationTypesMap[type.header] = type.translation;
    });
    return locationTypesMap;
}
```

Or use 'reduce':

```js
function createTypesWithTranslationsRecords(types: { header: string; translation: string }[]): Record<string, string> {
    return types.reduce((pre, type) => ({
        ...pre,
        [type.header]: type.translation,
    }), {});
}
```